# Is this the right performance using C++ and epoll in WSL2 if we consider it a black box testing?

Tags: c++, server, concurrency, epoll

I am recently working on a simple HTTP server project using C++ and epoll facility running on Ubuntu in WSL2. Is this the right performance if I implement epoll facility correctly in this context? Or it is much lower than the expected performance, which means I did something wrong.

Here is my laptop specification:
Processor   12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1255U
Installed RAM   16.0 GB (15.7 GB usable)
Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 23H2

I implement non-blocking sockets. There are ten working threads that read the request and write the response. I don't do any parse so far. So the server just sends a char array directly every time whatever it receives. There is also a main thread receiving events from `epoll_wait` and put events on a queue.

I test it by artillery running in WSL2 too on the same laptop. I close all other software. The test script is:

```
config:
  target: http://127.0.0.1:8086
  phases:
    - duration: 1
      arrivalRate: 10010
      name: Sustained peak load
  plugins:
    apdex: {}
  apdex:
    threshold: 100

scenarios:
  - flow:
      - loop:
        - get:
            url: "/"
        count: 40
```

The result is:

```
All VUs finished. Total time: 31 seconds

--------------------------------
Summary report @ 14:22:39(-0800)
--------------------------------

apdex.frustrated: .............................................................. 0
apdex.satisfied: ............................................................... 397875
apdex.tolerated: ............................................................... 2525
http.codes.200: ................................................................ 400400
http.downloaded_bytes: ......................................................... 86486400
http.request_rate: ............................................................. 14877/sec
http.requests: ................................................................. 400400
http.response_time:
  min: ......................................................................... 0
  max: ......................................................................... 300
  mean: ........................................................................ 29.4
  median: ...................................................................... 26.8
  p95: ......................................................................... 48.9
  p99: ......................................................................... 80.6
http.responses: ................................................................ 400400
vusers.completed: .............................................................. 10010
vusers.created: ................................................................ 10010
vusers.created_by_name.0: ...................................................... 10010
vusers.failed: ................................................................. 0
vusers.session_length:
  min: ......................................................................... 175.2
  max: ......................................................................... 2414.5
  mean: ........................................................................ 1230.5
  median: ...................................................................... 1176.4
  p95: ......................................................................... 1720.2
  p99: ......................................................................... 2101.1

Apdex score: 0.996846903096903 (excellent)
```

The code is long so it will take much time to read. But if it is necessary, I can put the code here.

Comment: I find it hard to see what bottleneck you are actually testing since you involve so many potential bottlenecks in the figures you present. It also makes it hard to say if the result is right or wrong (to me). When I've tested one specific thing in WSL2 compiled with clang++ or g++, it has performed a little worse than the same thing compiled with MSVC, but only very slightly and I have also tested very specific things.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. Could you please list a few most possible potential bottlenecks? I have found one tutorial that tested by webbench that can reach 5,000,000 pages/min. That is about 80000 pages/sec. That is so much higher than mine ( 14877/sec ). I couldn't find any essential differences between that tutorial and my code. So I am confused why that tutorial's performance is so high. I also tested my project by siege, but when I set `-c` over 1000, there are errors `[error] socket: read error Resource temporarily unavailable sock.c:635: Resource temporarily unavailable`. @TedLyngmo

Comment: _"Could you please list a few most possible potential bottlenecks?"_ - No, the bottlenecks that matters to me may not matter to someone else. It would make my list useless. Instead, present what _you_ need benchmarked.  Present how you presented that very thing and - if you are not convinced yourself, ask about the result.